# GitHub: how to maintain two different versions of files different in repositories?

Tags: version-control, github, versioning

Should I use `.gitignore` for this?

I want to maintain an `.htaccess` file in my local repository which is also the root directory of apache. The `.htaccess` file is different from what I have in a remote repository which also serves as my production server.

What should I do so that I have a "generic" `.htaccess` in the github repository while all other repositories may maintain their own copies which will not be uploaded to any of the remote repositories? I want the file to be retained locally only.

This is also the same case for configuration files, for instance, `config.php` contains database username/host/password/name which may be different among the repositories.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of ignoring the files, you could create a "branch" just for the production server, always merging the "master" changes inside that new branch before every deploy. In the production branch, you can commit configuration changes that apply only to the production environment.

This same strategy applies to any number of environments.

Remember: never merge the "production" branch back to "master", otherwise you'll end up with a lot of problems with the config files. If you need to fix something on production, use a "bugfix" branch, starting on the most recent master commit that is merged into production, merging it back to production AND master after the work is done.